# Creating a List Column with SharePoint Online Management Shell

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell

I need to create a few columns on a SharePoint Online List, I've been following [this](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2022/03/add-column-to-list-in-sharepoint-online-using-powershell.html) guide and with the following basic script I get no error, but also no column is created:

```
$FieldID = New-Guid
$FieldSchema = "<Field Type='Text' ID='$FieldID' Name='Test_x0020_Field' StaticName='Test_x0020_Field' DisplayName='Test Field'  Description='a'  Required='FALSE' EnforceUniqueValues='FALSE' MaxLength='255' />"
$NewField = $List.Fields.AddFieldAsXml($FieldSchema,$True,[Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.AddFieldOptions]::AddFieldInternalNameHint)
$Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
```

I tried running `$List.Update()` before `$Ctx.ExecuteQuery()` to see if that made any changes but it didn't.

I know the list is loaded, and I can call `$List.Fields |Select-Object Title` to see that my field was not created.

What else am I missing?

Importantly **I'm not using PnP, only SharePoint Online Management Shell**.